# Corrupted frame in VMR9

Tags: rendering, windows-10, directshow

I wrote a Directshow filter for the desktop capture.  Set it into the graph  and 
get the corrupted frames in VMR9. But my grabber, set before VMR9, get the good frames.

Details are in the following pictures:

1. The full graph
   [image]
2. The frames from my grabbers
   [image]
3. The frames on VMR9
   [image]

I use MS Win10 an the window 640x480 for VMR9.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's hardly anything different from [Handling Format Changes from the Video Renderer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd388901). However my bet is it's not just stride. Your grabber accepts 32-bit RGB as if it can handle it, but keeps sending 24-bit RGB afterwards.

Comment: Thanks, Roman! I moved my filter from RGB24 to RGB32 and changed the buffer's size, the filter worked well

Answer (score 0):

The filter worked in RGB24, must be in RGB32

Thanks all